# How to export prototypes in node.js

Tags: node.js, export, prototype

In my `db` library file, I have:

```
exports.slave = ->
  connection = mysql.createConnection
    host: config.database.slave.host
    user: config.database.slave.username
    password: config.database.slave.password
    database: config.database.slave.database

  connection.connect()

  return connection
```

which returns `connection` if I run `db.slave().query("WHATEVER")` and executes properly. How can I extend and export a prototype, so I can just use: `db.slave.query("WAHTEVER")` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard node convention is to export a single object. This object can whatever you want

```
var config = {
  database: ...
}
var mysql = require('mysql')
function setupSlave() {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection
    host: config.database.slave.host
    user: config.database.slave.username
    password: config.database.slave.password
    database: config.database.slave.database
  connection.connect()
  return connection
}
var slave = setupSlave()
module.exports = slave
```

If you instead want to export `slave()` instead of `slave` you can do that as well

```
var config = {
  database: ...
}
var mysql = require('mysql')
function setupSlave() {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection
    host: config.database.slave.host
    user: config.database.slave.username
    password: config.database.slave.password
    database: config.database.slave.database
  connection.connect()
  return connection
}
var slave = setupSlave()
module.exports = slave()
```